# Securing PHP website on LAN server - is securing SESSION, prepared statements and HTTPS enough?

Tags: php, session, https, mysqli

I'm developing a website that will be accessible from LAN only. I still wish to make it as safe as possible.

From web point of view, is it enough to add SESSION check to every PHP file, use prepared mysqli statements and use HTTPS?

I will be more specific:

I'm checking every PHP page with this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['UA'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] || $_SESSION['IP'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] || time() - $_SESSION['timeout']>=600){
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location:index.php');
```

I also regenerate session ID on every page, just to be sure. So I'm checking user's user agent, IP address, activity timeout and a session variable "login".

For mysql connection I mostly use prepared statements (mysqli) for security and performance, in cases I don't or can't use prepared statement, I always do real_escape_string() when dealing with client data.

I will also allow HTTPS only, with checking `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = "on"`.

The server is never setting any cookies, except PHPSSID.

Is this all I can do to make my website secure, or is there anything else? I found bits and pieces all over the web how to secure a website, but nothing on one place, so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I may be terribly wrong, but I think that should be enough for a LAN server

Comment: This seems more than secure for a server accessible on a LAN only.

Answer (score 1):

A better site for this question may be https://security.stackexchange.com/

Although your LAN web server would be *safer* know that it's not bulletproof. Your client machines could be one of the major vectors for insecurity in a LAN environment especially if they also can access and are exposed to the outside internet. Leaving them open to things like [network eavesdropping](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Network_Eavesdropping) or [Man-in-the-middle](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks.

Here is [A Guide to Building Secure Web Applications and Web Services](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_Table_of_Contents)

Comment: +1 because of giving something *"all in one place"* OP is concerned about. Will it help? We don't know ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check the guide, perhaps I will know something more about it. What I exactly wanted to hear is that the server is not "bulletproof", I will still search for more options to protect it altough I do not expect at all any kind of thread for this server application. I will now focus more on protecting the database and remote access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your web server configuration you could block all request that don't come from your LAN just as an extra precaution.

Other than that it seems more than enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the server will only have LAN IP and will be impossible to access it from outside, but I guess I still will add this to htaccess. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you validate as much of the data the user makes to make sure it's valid or something the user should be giving you and if you have to redisplay the data they gave you or the data someone else gave you (ie you stored it in the db for later) then make sure you use htmlenties to make it so JavaScript won't work in the data. If you are putting their data in javascript then instead use addslashes. A lot of what you said is very good as well.

As a random side note I'd validate that the session id they are giving you is a valid session id ie ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{26,40}$

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will think about validating session id, seams like a pretty good idea. I will also double check passing all POST variables from web forms wether there's possibility of misuse. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the attack surface.

It looks like that you have PHP files lying around open to be requested. For the file you know this is the case you write a code-chunk on top to "protect" them.

Instead move all this into a private directory and have only a single point of entry in the webroot, like `index.php`. As this would be the only point, you can validate if a request should be allowed at a central place. That means you can not forget one file to protect and you can improve the situation in a single place if you want to add additional checks.

Example configuration with a PHP file (Apache HTTPD):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In a PHP script you can obtain the URI/URL by making use of special variables like [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Yes there is over 40 PHP files and each one of them is protected the same way, unaccessible without proper session. Merging all files in one index.php is not right now very good idea, since the project is already finished and ready for deployment to the customers and this will require much more of tweaks and further testing.

If I understand correctly, the only benefit would be "single point of failure" and not forgetting to protect other files, which can simply not happen because of testing policy. Perhaps I didn't understand correctly and I am wrong?

Comment: No, you don't merge them all inside index.php. You keep them separate, but you give the system a single entry point. The files then just don't lie publicly requestable around any longer because move into a directory that can not be access via a URL. Depending on your skills, this can be quickly integrated, but if the work is already done and you don't feel save with such a change, double-check all security checks are in place and effective.

Comment: Now I understand :) sounds great, will definitely try that altho planning to deploy nginx, definitely something like that will work there too. thanks again, this sounds great.